# Check for uniqueness of closed shape

Tags: integration, analytic-geometry

I am currently working on my master thesis and part of my master thesis involves the following problem:

Given a circular shape (doesn't need to be a circle, just anything that closed). Does specifying the following values uniquely identify the circular shape?

$$
s_x = \oint_S x dS \\
s_y = \oint_S y dS \\
A   = \oint_S 1 dS \\
A_m = \oint_S (x,y) \times dS \\
I_x = \oint_S \left(x-\frac{s_x}{A}\right)^2 dS \\
I_y = \oint_S \left(y-\frac{s_y}{A}\right)^2 dS
$$

I am not sure if the equation for $A_m$ is correct but it should equal the enclosed area.

I am not interested in finding an equation which identifies the shape. My gut feeling tells me that there must be multiple shapes that satisfy this. Ideally infinitely many but I have no idea on how to even remotely prove this. It's even sufficient to simply find two shapes which have the same properties as listed above.

I came up with shapes that have similar properties but they were always transformable into the other by mirroring and rotating.

I am wondering what methods I could employ or is there some trick you guys are seeing?

I appreciate any input,
Finn

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to drop some of the fixed quantities.   What if just the first $3$ match, say?  Or the first $4$?

Comment: My efforts began by identifying shapes which I could only find using mirroring, translation and rotation. I am not really coming from the fields of math so I am just trying to find a path forward. I am not directly looking for an answer to the overall problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different thoughts (too long for a mere comment).

- You are conscious that such a finite set (here 6 of them) cannot "capture" the infinite varieties of closed curves (i.e., homeomorphic to a circle). As you say that you would like to have an argument against "finiteness", think to the technique called "**Fourier descriptors**". See for example [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245411238_Particle_shape_characterization_using_Fourier_analysis). The idea is simple, consider your curve parametrized by its **curvilinear abscissa** traditionally called $s$, which is a periodic function (once you have made a complete turn, you begin again...). Make a Fourier expansion of $x(s)$ and y(s) : we need all coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ for the reconstruction of the curve... But it is true also that by taking a finite sufficient number among the first ones, you will have a satisfying reconstruction.
- I think you should normalize your data, by having your curves all with unit area, in order in particular to be able to compare them. Indeed, enclosed area doesn't give any information about the shape itself.
- You could consider a "small world approach" by taking a subset of all possible curves in order to better understand them, and possibly be able to characterize them by your parameters ? Consider for example closed splines or closed NURBS defined for example by a few points (the same ones for all curves).

Comment: I think the first part you mentioned is something I'd like to do. I will look into the links, before that, you are saying that we have a finite set of 6 values. But each of these values can take any real number, so that would lead to infinite combinations. Could I think about it as different kinds of infinities? that there are more infinitely many shapes than i can have combinations of my 6 values? This would basically prove my point bc. I could argue that every shape maps to my values and since there are more shapes, some shapes must map to the same values.

Comment: I agree with this point of view. The space of shapes is infinite-dimensional. Besides, using keywords "space of shapes" and "descriptors" for a Google query (that I should have done before), one gets a wealth of information ; here is [good presentation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097849321000790) mentionning in particular Fourier descriptors.

Comment: I am in fact familiar with Fourier descriptors. I am still slightly wondering how one would even begin a proof in this area. I mean okay, I can describe my shape using infinite amounts of Fourier coefficients. But that doesn't tell me if it's sufficient to describe it using the finite amount of integral values. Or does it?

Comment: In some cases, the descriptors you give could be sufficient for the fulfillment of your objective, in particular if it is a discrimination task. I would be interested to know which type of application you have in sight.

Comment: The specifics deal with structural mechanical properties of cross sections. the mentioned values resemble stiffness, weight and various properties in mechanical engineering. 

So what you would propose that I actually evaluate the integral on the Fourier transformation?

Comment: I just found an infinite amount of counterexamples which prove my point. I think counterexamples are simply the easiest way of proving / disproving something :)